# Angular 2 Flex Layout Align Icon Right

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I am having trouble aligning items using Angular Flex Layout.

The below snipper doesnt align the `<md-icon>` to the right of the header which is what I intend it to do.

Any advice on how to accomplish this?

`<div class="flex-item" fxFlex fxFlexAlign="end end">`

```html
<md-card style="background-color:white;">
   <md-card-header style="background-color:white;">
      <md-card-title>Swap Card</md-card-title>
      <div class="flex-item" fxFlex fxFlexAlign="end end">
         <md-icon>add_a_photo</md-icon>
         Icon
      </div>
   </md-card-header>
   <md-card-content>
   </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add an empty span of flexible length in between:

```
<md-card>
  <md-card-header>
    <md-card-title>Swap Card</md-card-title>
    <span fxFlex></span>
    <md-icon>add_a_photo</md-icon>
  </md-card-header>
  <md-card-content>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Answer (score 12):

You were on right track, just needed to add the correct `fxFlexAlign` parameters. For your problem, you will need.

```
fxLayoutAlign="end start"
```

I have tested it in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7L3iqWCo9burdKTmmSfZ?p=preview).

html:

```
<md-card style="background-color:white;">
    <md-card-header style="background-color:white;">
        <md-card-title>Swap Card</md-card-title>
          <div class="flex-item" 
               fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="end start">
            <md-icon>add_a_photo</md-icon>
              Icon
          </div>
        </md-card-header>
    <md-card-content>
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

You can also learn about `fxLayoutAlign` using this [documentation example](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs).

Comment: this one is a more appropriate answer